# How to make docker-compose scale start dependencies?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There is a setup with 1...N application containers which are connected to different backend services. The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
services:
  backend1:
    ...
  backend2:
    ...
  application:
    ...
    depends_on:
      backend1:
        condition: service_healthy
      backend2:
        condition: service_healthy
```

When starting multiple instances of the application with `docker-compose scale  SERVICE=INSTANCES` the result is this

```
$ docker-compose scale application=2
Creating and starting application_1 ... done
Creating and starting application_2 ... done
$ docker ps -a 
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE               COMMAND   CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS   NAMES
f4e274552239    application_image   ...       4 minutes ago    Up 4 minutes (unhealthy)           application_1
39f28173087c    application_image   ...       4 minutes ago    Up 4 minutes (unhealthy)           application_2
```

Obviously, the dependencies are not started. When the a single instance of the service is started instead with `docker-compose up application`, the dependencies are started correctly:

```
$ docker-compose up -d application
Creating backend1_1
Creating backend2_1
Creating application_1
```

After that, a second instance can be added docker `scale`:

```
$ docker-compose scale application=2
Creating and starting application_2 ... done
```

This works fine. But is there some way to let `docker-compose scale` also start the dependencies? If not, what might be the rationale behind that behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to do this right now. There is a long, running [issue commentary](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1661) on this topic.

[One of the comments](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1661#issuecomment-270886347) mentions that it will be available in version 3 of the schema.

I've tried a minimal version locally:

```
version: '2'

services:
  a:
    image: alpine
    links:
      - b
    command: sleep 10

  b:
    image: alpine
    command: sleep 10
```

And the `up` doesn't work with scale. However (and you probably know this already), you can name all the services in your command, so

`docker-compose scale a=2 b=2`

creates two of both and did the correct linking.